# Why does CTE run select twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have two CTEs, the first runs a 'select top n' to get a sample of records, then the second splits each record producing 2 rows for each record.

I have reproduced with fake data, using newid() to determine the sorting order of the sample.

```
declare @testtab table (Id bigint identity (1,1), ColA varchar(10), ColB varchar(10))
-- generate 1000 sample records
declare @cnt int = 0
while (@cnt<1000)
begin
    insert @testtab(ColA, ColB) values ('A'+convert(varchar,@cnt), 'B'+convert(varchar,@cnt))
    set @cnt+=1
end

;with SampleRecs as(
select top 1 * from @testtab order by newid()
)
,SplitRecs as (
select 0 Pos,Id,ColA Col from SampleRecs
union all
select 1, id, ColB col from SampleRecs
)
select * from SplitRecs
order by id, pos
```

The expected end result is 2 rows for each input row is something like:

```
Pos Id  Col
0   720 A719
1   720 A719
```

However, what I get is something like

```
Pos Id  Col
0   720 A719
1   774 B773
```

So the "top 1" in CTE appears to be running twice in the CTE2.

Is this normal? Can anyone point me towards any documentation that can explain this behavior?

Comment: because the cte you are selecting is splitrecs which has a UNION ALL so it takes a top 1 then unions anohter top 1 and you get 2 results

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are referencing the first `CTE` twice in the second `CTE` via the `UNION ALL`.

`CTE`s are essentially temporary views that are discarded after they are called.  So each call to the first `CTE` will execute the `SELECT` statement separately, and since your `ORDER BY` is over `NEWID()`, you can expect to get a different `TOP 1` result for both executions.

Replacing the `CTE` reference in your query with the actual statement helps to illustrate what is happening:

`SampleRecs` is defined as:

> select top 1 * from @testtab order by newid()

So replacing all references with that sub-query, will give you the following:

```
;With SplitRecs As
(
    Select  0       As Pos,
            Id,
            ColA    As Col
    From    (Select Top 1 * From @testtab Order By NewId()) As A
    Union All
    Select  1       As Pos,
            Id,
            ColB    As Col
    From    (Select Top 1 * From @testtab Order By NewId()) As B
)
Select  *
From    SplitRecs
Order By Id, pos
```

You will get the same behaviour from this as you do with the `CTE` variant.

To get the results you're expecting, you can do the following, instead, which leverages a `CROSS JOIN` to seed the `Pos` value:

```
Select      X.Pos   As Pos,
            Id,
            ColA    As Col
From        (Select Top 1 * From @testtab Order By NewId()) As A
Cross Join  (Select 0 As Pos Union All Select 1) As X
Order By    X.Pos
```

Comment: Doesn't this make CTEs then very inefficient? Convenient, yes, but inefficient. Better off taking the trouble of creating then deleting temp tables? From the way they were described in various articels, I was always under the impression CTEs were equivalent to temp tables, but this is a very significant difference.